# How to detect math operator on current html page so that my code can assign the correct sum

Tags: javascript

I have been working on a maths project for my son, and am currently struggling to attach the correct maths sum to the correct math operator currently shown on the website.

The function mathOperator() aims to identify what math operator is currently on page and then supply the correct sum.

Then i am trying to check if the textContent of the chosen clicked answer matches that sum or not using the anonymous function below mathOpertor().

I am getting no errors in the console but the code is annoyingly just adding num1 and num2 together no mater which math operator is currently active.

I figure the problem is within the lines:

```
let operator = num1 + num2;
      if (this.textContent == operator) { }
```

I figured (let operator) would be mutated to the condition that was met within the mathOperator() function, but this is not the case!

Here is my code below:

```
    //Globals
const arrLength = 10
const randomArr = []

//push random numbers to randomArr.
for (let i=0; i<arrLength; i++) {
  randomArr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
}



//DOM targets
//first and second numbers.
const num1 = document.getElementById("num1").textContent = randomArr[0];
const num2 = document.getElementById("num2").textContent = randomArr[1];

//Multiple choice answers
let option1 = document.getElementById("option1").textContent = randomArr[2];
let option2 = document.getElementById("option2").textContent = randomArr[3];
let option3 = document.getElementById("option3").textContent = randomArr[4];

//Places the correct asnwer randomly within the 3 multiple choice answers.
const correctAnswerPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
document.querySelectorAll(".options h1")[correctAnswerPosition].textContent = num1 + num2;

//function to decide how to calculate equation depending on what HTMLpage you are on.
function mathoperators(sum) {
  if (document.querySelector(".wrapper div").children[1].textContent == "+") {
    sum = num1 + num2;
  } else if (document.querySelector(".wrapper div").children[1].textContent == "-") {
    sum = num1 - num2;
  } else if (document.querySelector(".wrapper div").children[1].textContent == "*") {
    sum = num1 * num2;
  } else if (document.querySelector(".wrapper div").children[1].textContent == "/") {
    sum = num1 / num2;
  }
}

//What do to if you pick right or wrong answer.
for (let a=0; a<document.querySelectorAll(".options").length; a++) {
//targets the 3 divs that contain random incorrect answers plus correct answer.
document.querySelectorAll(".options")[a].addEventListener("click", function() {
let operator = num1 + num2;
  if (this.textContent == operator) { //problem here i don't know how to connect this to sum in math operators function.
    const correct = new Audio("Sounds/correct.mp3");
    correct.play();
    document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.display="none";
    document.querySelector(".well-done").style.display="block";

    setTimeout(function() {
      location.reload();
    }, 3000);
  } else {
    const incorrect = new Audio("Sounds/incorrect.mp3");
    incorrect.play();
  }
mathoperators(operator)
})
}


function reload() {
  reload = location.reload();
}
```

Thankyou for your time in advance.

Comment: You have the correct logic in `mathoperators` already, but you don't really use it. `return` the result instead of assigning to a local `sum` variable, and then call the function instead of doing `let operator = num1 + num2;`

Answer (score 0):

@ bergi, Thanks very much this is the push in the right direction I needed, the changes have been made below:

```
function mathoperators() {
  if (document.querySelector(".wrapper div").children[1].textContent == "+") {
    return num1 + num2;
  } else if (document.querySelector(".wrapper div").children[1].textContent == "-") {
    return num1 - num2;
  } else if (document.querySelector(".wrapper div").children[1].textContent == "*") {
    return num1 * num2;
  } else if (document.querySelector(".wrapper div").children[1].textContent == "/") {
    return num1 / num2; 
  }
}

//What do to if you pick right or wrong answer.
for (let a=0; a<document.querySelectorAll(".options").length; a++) {

document.querySelectorAll(".options")[a].addEventListener("click", function() {
const number = parseFloat(this.textContent)
  if (mathoperators() === number) {
    const correct = new Audio("Sounds/correct.mp3");
    correct.play();
    document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.display="none";
    document.querySelector(".well-done").style.display="block";
```

After this I also noticed that the below needed changing so that it was equal to mathOperator() and not num1 + num2;.

```
//Places the correct asnwer randomy within the 3 multiple choice answers.
const correctAnswerPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
document.querySelectorAll(".options h1")[correctAnswerPosition].textContent = mathoperators();
```

Thanks for your help Bergi.